# How to add a listener to the DONE button in document viewer

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have opened a PDF file by using document viewer in titanium.

`var viewer = Ti.UI.iOS.createDocumentViewer({
    url: "sample.pdf"
 });
 viewer.show();`

It will open a viewer with a "DONE" button on top left, when clicks , closes this viewer. May I know to handle that listener?

Thanks,
Swathi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't listen directly for the 'click' event on that button.
But you could listen for the '**unload**' event! It is fired when the document is dismissed (that is to say, after you have clicked on the "DONE" button)

```
var viewer = Ti.UI.iOS.createDocumentViewer({
    url: "sample.pdf"
});
viewer.addEventListener('unload', function(e) {
    // something to do after the document has been dismissed
});
viewer.show();
```

More info about the 'unload' event [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.DocumentViewer-event-unload)